# Angular 2 - how to give copy option on angular matTooltip

Tags: angular, copy, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using matTooltip to show tooltip in Angular. I am facing two issues -

1) I want to give copy option on matTooltip to copy tooltip text. How to give it.

2) My second issues is since my tooltip text is large or long it is not getting shown completely on the tooltip it is wrapped with three dots at end(e.g. "Thisistooltip...").

Please guide if anyone faced this same issue.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I don't see an _issue_ but some googling and doc crawling. Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

### 1- Copy Text

You can use ***ngxClipboard*** for copying...

```
<a 
   ngxClipboard
   (click)="copyToClipboard()"
   [cbContent]="textYouNeedToCopy" />
</a>
```

Also you need to add **FormsModule** && **ClipboardModule** in your app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import { ClipboardModule } from 'ngx-clipboard';
```

Add it to the imports too...

### 2- Show full text

I didn't faced this issue but I found a git issue may be this is useful:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3531

It explicitly give css to the tool-tip and here's the css

```
.mat-tooltip {
    max-width: 50px;
    /* or */
    /* width: 50px; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But you have give option for copying of text but how to give copy button or option on tooltip

Comment: Ok I get you now, you wish to make the tool-tip clickable, right?

You probably then have to make it by yourself and if any issue occurs then we can help you... For now you can take this as a reference: (https://codepen.io/jamilhijjawi/pen/lIwbK) it uses jQuery but you can easily convert it to JavaScript...

Comment: OP is using Angular, **not** the formal AngularJS 1.x versions.